# Running Functions in GUI matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Continuing my struggle against GUI's, I have run into another road block.

Ive successfully created a button that opens a file as a string, and places it in a text box in my GUI like so.

```
 [filename, pathname] = ...
     uigetfile({'*.m';'*.mdl';'*.mat';'*.*'},'File Selector');

set(handles.Textbox1, 'string', fullfile(pathname,filename));
```

But now I cannot seem to use a function on the acquired file. Ive tried doing

```
  str = get(handles.Textbox1,'string');
Histogram(str); %Histogram is a function that I created.
```

But im getting the following errors

> ??? Error using ==> Histogram Too many input arguments.
>
> Error in ==> VarunGUI>pushbutton2_Callback at 94 Histogram(str);
>
> Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
>           feval(varargin{:});
>
> Error in ==> VarunGUI at 42
>       gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
>
> Error in ==>
>   @(hObject,eventdata)VarunGUI('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>
> ??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Is my code for calling the function to blame, or is the function itself? I'm having trouble understanding how to alter the function to work on the called image, so that may be my problem, the function begins with the following code.

```
function Histogram
clear;
clc;
fid = fopen('');
myimage = fread(fid, [512, 683], '*uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

Is there a certain variable I need to place in the '' to make the GUI act in the manner to which I would like it? Question ran a little long, but please tell me if there is anything else you need to see in order to assist me, any guidance or tips would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `dbstop if error` and figuring out where exactly strange things become visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is that call `Histogram` and pass it `str`:

```
Histogram(str)
```

But you don't define `Histogram` to expect input:

```
function Histogram
```

What you need is something like this:

```
function Histogram(str)

% do something with str
```

Comment: @schorsch Im not entirely sure how I would "definte Histogram to expect input" as you say.

Comment: @m_power ... debugging Matlab ... practice makes the master ;-)

Comment: @user2475404 : what do you expect `Histogram` to do with the `str`?

Comment: well the Histogram function was supposed to create a histogram with certain parameters.

Comment: @user2475404 : if you want to use the `str` variable in `Histogram`, just change the first line of your function definition along the lines of the third code-block in my answer.

Comment: I did what you said in the function definition, but the button still results in errors??? Error using ==> fread
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in ==> Histogram at 5
myimage = fread(fid, [512, 683], '*uint8');

Error in ==> VarunGUI>pushbutton2_Callback at 94
Histogram

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> VarunGUI at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)VarunGUI('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: @user2475404 This is a new error. Either edit your question, or accept one of the answers here and ask a new question.

Comment: Ill ask another question than, thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Histogram` function doesn't have an input, so it fails when you call it : `Histogram(str)`

Answer (score 1):

I got this y'all!

Change your histogram function to this: (literally copy and paste what's below)

```
function Histogram(str) %Add input argument
%clear %DO NOT USE CLEAR in a function, the benefit of using a function is you don't have to %clear anything :)
clc;
fid = fopen(str); %Use input argument
myimage = fread(fid, [512, 683]); %take off *uint8
fclose(fid);
```

Read MATLAB's documentation, it is fantastic, and would allow you to see why fread and uint8 don't go together in a matter of seconds (seriously less than 20 seconds would give you your answer) and it would also solve all your other extremely basic issues you are having.

Comment: reading someone's mind, probably ... you might be able to copy/paste this answer to the new question which may be in the making

Comment: Ill erase my newly made question, you are a lifesaver, thank you sir.